# Linux friendly TV tuner/receiver

Tags: drivers

My USB TV tuner (an [ENUTV-2](http://www.encore-usa.com/ma/taxonomy/term/168/all)) just stopped working and now I have to buy a new one. While I was browsing options, I realized my biggest priority was to get one that had Linux drivers (lack of them was my biggest annoyance with the old tuner).

Can anyone recommend a TV tuner that has Linux drivers? It could be either PCI-E card or a USB box, my priority is Linux support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video4linux project keeps [lists of supported cards](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Device_Information), for example, [analog PCI-e cards](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Video_via_PCI_Express_%28PCIe%29) and [analog USB devices](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Video_via_USB).

`linux` (the kernel) itself has a list of supported tuners under `/Documentation/video4linux/CARDLIST.tuner`.